# What’s the difference between 你去干嘛 and 你去吗?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conversation

I am sure if they mean the same. If there are some differences between them, what are those? When and how to use each of them? Thanks.

Comment: why do you think they mean the same?

Answer (score 4):

They don't mean the same.

- "你去干嘛?" means "What are you going to do?" or maybe "Why are you going?" depending on the context.
- "你去吗?" means "Are you going?"

Examples:

> A: 我出去一会 = I'm leaving for a while. B: 你去干嘛? = What are you going to do?
>
> A: 我去开会了 = I'm going to attend the meeting. B: 这会是给经理开的, 你去干嘛? = The meeting is intended for managers. Why are you going?
>
> A: 我要去吃午饭, 你去吗 = I'm leaving for lunch. Are you going (with me)?